# Arrow end type [-] unknown - even though library is loaded

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am a beginner with LaTex and not comfortable enough to switch over just yet. At the moment I mainly use the `smartdiagram` package to easily produce high-quality flow diagrams for various documents and presentations.

For this use case I created a number of templates. Here are two examples based on them.

This one works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % smartdiagram base package
\usepackage{smartdiagram} % used for generating diagrams                           
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % additional arrows
\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{                                                                                           
% ARROWS
  arrow tip={stealth},
}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{ % set orientation (horizontal/vertical)
A,B,C,D
}
\end{document}
```

This one doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % smartdiagram base package
\usepackage{smartdiagram} % used for generating diagrams                           
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % additional arrows
\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{                                                                                           
% ARROWS
  arrow tip={|-|},
}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{ % set orientation (horizontal/vertical)
A,B,C,D
}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I am struggling with the arrow library. If I set smartdiagram's `arrow tip` parameter to a bracket-like TikZ arrow, LaTex returns the following error message:

```
flow_diagram.tex.swp:119: Package pgf Error: Arrow
 end type ``[-]'' unknown.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
```

I took this arrow definition from TikZ' manual (p. 257), where a number of bracket-like arrow tips and their respective names are listed.

Any other arrow tip type I can render with this template without any problems, it's only these bracket-type arrows I struggle with.

Can you please tell me, if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I cannot compile your example as their seem to be some problems with `smartdiagram`s pgf-keys. Could you please reduce your MWE!

Comment: @Toscho Sorry about the long example. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Well, it could be a bug of the package under some point of views or not. Actually the package does not consider at the moment (but I think it's a nice add) the possibility of having arrows on both sides of a path (i.e. `<->`) thus the key `arrow tip` only addresses the `-tip`. This means that `arrow tip=[-]` is wrong, but `arrow tip=[` or `arrow tip=]` are perfectly right (even without braces).

Comment: @Toscho: if you have problems with the keys you have very likely the version 0.1 of the package, but for two weeks there's on CTAN version 0.2.

Comment: BTW: What's the reason, to rename the existing pgf keys?

Comment: @Toscho: The package is simply an high level TikZ construction, so there's a separate name space for smartdiagram keys. These keys ultimately pass their values to TikZ keys, but it's not true that I've just renamed existing pgfkeys. Indeed, `planet size` and `satellite size` (and there are many others) both refer to the same `minimum size` TikZ key, just to make an example.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: The single bracket works great, thank you! I see now what went wrong. To be honest, I didn't even realize that the arrow definitions had an inbuilt way of choosing between single and double arrows! That's what happens when you try to work with LaTeX without knowing all too much about it, haha. I agree, though, an option to choose between single and double arrows would be pretty useful.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Sorry, my comment was meant on the whole of your package. I don't even know that. I was just referring to the arrows. Why don't you use the `arrows` key but your own `arrow tip` key which passes its value to `tikz`s `arrows` key?

Comment: @Toscho: you're welcome, don't mind. `:)` The reason is simple: all the personalization is done via `\smartdiagramset` which automatically uses as path `/smart diagram/` therefore usual TikZ keys wouldn't apply since their path is in general `/tikz/`. In the specific, the `arrow tip` stores the value inside a macro `\arrowtip` and then its value is passed as `>=\arrowtip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pgf` doesn't know the arrow tip `[-]`. This is two arrow tips together. You can use `\draw[{[-]}](0,0)--(1,0);` or `\draw[<->,arrows={[-]}] (a)--(b);` if you loaded `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}` before.

If this happens only with the `[-]` arrow tips, it might be in bug in `smartdiagram` due to not dealing properly with the brackets (they need always be enclosed in `{}`.

Comment: I just checked again and this happens for any type of bracket-like arrow tip in a smartdiagram environment even if there is a proper enclosure in `{}`. In a tikzpicture environment, OTOH, everything works fine. So as you said it's likely a bug in smartdiagram. I will try to contact the maintainer about it. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I have been looking for this tip for at least 45mn. Thanks !