# arrow end type unknown

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

In an earlier question [Arrow end type [-] unknown - even though library is loaded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103948/arrow-end-type-unknown-even-though-library-is-loaded) the consensus was that the bug "arrow end type unknown" is because of the wrong environment (smartdiagram), and that in `tikzpicture` everything should be fine.  But I am trying to run with the `tikzpicture` and it still complaining about "arrow end type unknown". Help!

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalefnt}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\lineticktop#1#2{
  \draw[-] ({#1},3.075) node [anchor=south] {#2} -- (#1,2.925) ;
}

\def\linetickbot#1#2{
  \draw[-] ({#1},-0.075) node [anchor=north] {#2} -- (#1,0.075) ;
}

\def\microscope#1{
  \draw [thick,-         ] (#1 -0.25,2.15) -- (#1+0,3) -- (#1 +0.25,2.15) ;
  \draw [thick,fill=white] (#1 +0.00,1.50) circle (1) ;  
  \fill [white           ] (#1 -0.25,2.15) -- (#1+0,3) -- (#1 +0.25,2.15) ;
  \draw [thick,blue,->   ](#1-0.95,1.5) -- (#1+0.95,1.5) ;
}

\def\microtick#1#2#3#4#5#6{
  \draw [-,#5] (#1+0.375*#2,1.5+#3) node [anchor=#6,font=\small] {#4} -- (#1+0.375*#2,1.5-#3) ;
  \draw [red,thin] (#1+0.375*#2,1.3) to [out=-90,in=90] (#1+0.00,0.6);
}

\begin {tikzpicture} [scale=2]
  \draw[blue,thick,->]      (-1.1,3) -- (4.1,3) coordinate (x axis);

  \microscope    {1.41}
  \microtick     {1.41}{-0.2}{0.1}{$r$}{}{south}
  \microtick     {1.41}{ 0.7}{0.05}{\tiny $r+\epsilon$}{blue}{south}
  \microtick     {1.41}{ 2.1}{0.05}{\tiny $r+\gamma$}  {blue}{south}
  \microtick     {1.41}{-1.7}{0.05}{\tiny $r+\eta$}    {blue}{south}
  \draw[red,->] (1.41,0.6) -- (1.41,0.325) node [anchor=west] {$\scriptstyle \operatorname{st}$} -- (1.41,0.15) ;

  \lineticktop{-1}{$-1$}
  \linetickbot{-1}{$-1$}
  \lineticktop{ 0}{$ 0$}
  \linetickbot{ 0}{$ 0$}
  \lineticktop{+1}{$ 1$}
  \linetickbot{+1}{$ 1$}
  \lineticktop{+2}{$ 2$}
  \linetickbot{+2}{$ 2$}
  \lineticktop{+3}{$ 3$}
  \linetickbot{+3}{$ 3$}
  \lineticktop{+4}{$ 4$}
  \linetickbot{+4}{$ 4$}

  \lineticktop{+1.41}{}
  \linetickbot{+1.41}{$ r$}

  \draw[->]      (-1.1,0) -- (4.1,0) coordinate (x axis);
\end {tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The system is complaining about the argument `{1.41}` of `\microscope` (as well as 100 additional errors :-) ).

Comment: Your code compiles fine here, without error. What exactly is the error?

Comment: It must be our outdated system.  As I mentioned, I get the error message  *arrow end type '' '' unknown.*

Comment: Could be. If you add `\listfiles` just before `\documentclass` a list of all packages loaded and their versions will be printed, so you could check which version of TikZ/pgf you have. But did you get the `arrow end type unknown` error for `\microscope`? There is no special arrow type used there (or anywhere else, for that matter), so that sounds a bit strange.

Comment: You might be right.  Here is the exact message I get:
 
*! Package pgf Error: Arrow end type `` '' unknown.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
  ...

l.2027   \microscope    {1.41}*

It could be that the complaint about the microscope is unrelated to the complaint about the arrow.  Will check the version now.

Comment: Ah, when it encounters `-` in the first `\draw` in `\microscope` it expects an arrow head, but as nothing (or just spaces) is found, it  complains. Try removing that `-`.

Comment: The "article" is version v1.4f from 2005. Otherwise I don't seem to get any dates on the pgf and tikz files.

Comment: TheRe is a list of packages near the end of the log file.

Comment: tikz is 2006 v1.10 (rcs-revision 1.68).

Comment: After I removed the dash, it started complaining about "illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)".  Thanks for all your patience!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12259/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-katz)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an outdated version of TikZ/pgf.